# How to set google static map font for city town label

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fonts

I need to set small font size of google static map. So, what are the required parameters to achieve the same thing. Since, i am using the below url to get static map

```
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={$randAppPhoto['latitude']},{$randAppPhoto['longitude']}&scale=2&size=700x400&maptype=terrain&markers={$randAppPhoto['latitude']},{$randAppPhoto['longitude']}&zoom=7&format=jpg&sensor=false
```

where, $randAppPhoto is an array in php which has dynamic lat , long

Comment: perhaps you should check out this issue, it worked for me [Set Label Size in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40490880/7239796)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to change the font for the texts on the maps. You can check a list of parameters for setting map styles [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps).

Answer (score -2):

Changing `scale=2` to `scale=1` in the URL will make the street name font smaller, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't make only the font smaller, but the entire map. The `scale` parameter is defined as affecting the number of pixels that are returned. i.e. scale=2 returns twice as many pixels as scale=1 while retaining the same coverage area and level of detail. [Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#URL_Parameters), [more info](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#scale_values)