# Set label size in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

This code is to set a caption in a label point, but
how to change the font size?

```
label: {text: marcadores[i][0], color: 'black', TAGFORFONTSIZE: valuesize}
```

My code:

```
<html lang='es'> 
<head> 
    <meta charset='UTF-8'> 
    <style type='text/css'> 
        #mapa { height: 500px; } 
    </style> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
        function initialize() { 
            var marcadores = [ 
                ['usu1', -5.31987835340327, -52.8212431459598],
                ['usu4', 42.3617, -3.6789] 
            ]; 

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), { 
                zoom: 7, 
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.503, -5.744), 
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
            }); 

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
            var marker, i; 

            for (i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {   
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2]), 
                    map: map, 
                    label: {text: marcadores[i][0], color: 'black'}
                }); 

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { 
                     return function() { 
                         infowindow.setContent(marcadores[i][0]); 
                         infowindow.open(map, marker); 
                     } 
                 })(marker, i)); 
             } 
         } 

         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id='mapa'></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 20):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel):

> **fontSize** Type:  string
>
> The font size of the label text (equivalent to the CSS font-size property). Default size is 14px.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2]),
  map: map,
  label: {
    text: marcadores[i][0],
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: "8px"
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5h8tbLxr/184/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var marcadores = [
    ['usu1', -5.31987835340327, -52.8212431459598],
    ['usu4', 42.3617, -3.6789]
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.503, -5.744),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2]),
      map: map,
      label: {
        text: marcadores[i][0],
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: "8px"
      }
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(marcadores[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapa {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="mapa"></div>
```